# Yii Advanced search at admin page does not work. Changed model->search() criteria

Tags: php, yii

I edited the criteria my model->search function to only view data with the same businessID but now the advanced search does not work.

Here is the code on my model at model->search()

```
  public function search() {
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('LOVEAGENT_ID', $this->LOVEAGENT_ID);
    $criteria->compare('FIRST_NAME', $this->FIRST_NAME, true);
    $criteria->compare('LAST_NAME', $this->LAST_NAME, true);
    $criteria->compare('DOB', $this->DOB, true);
    $criteria->compare('PASSWORD', $this->PASSWORD, true);
    ............


    $criteria->condition = 'BUSINESS_ID=:businessID';
    $criteria->params = array(':businessID' => Yii::app()->user->businessId);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                'criteria' => $criteria,
            ));
}
```

my admin controller:

```
   public function actionAdmin() {
        $model = new LoveAgentContactDetails('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values

        if (isset($_GET['LoveAgentContactDetails'])) {
            $model->attributes = $_GET['LoveAgentContactDetails'];
        }

        $this->render('admin', array(
            'model' => $model,
        ));
    }
```

and Cgrid view settings at view:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id' => 'love-agent-contact-details-grid',
'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
'filter' => $model,
'columns' => array(

    'FIRST_NAME',
    'LAST_NAME',
    'lastLoginTime',
    'created',

    array(
        'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
```

));

Answer (score 3):

Problem is here

```
 $criteria->condition = 'BUSINESS_ID=:businessID';
```

By this you rewtite previously prepared  conditions. You  can use `CDbCriteria::addCondition`, but the best way is

```
   $criteria->compare('BUSINESS_ID',Yii::app()->user->businessId);
```

Comment: this help me out on my own issues.  Can you drop a few more lines explaining why condition doesn't work, and the compare works?